# Prolog beginner help get current time

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence, swi-prolog

I am modifying the Eliza program http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall11/CSCI-GA.2110-003/documents/eliza.pl
trying to get it to print the system time when user asks - What Time is it?
After hours of reading through manual I got my get_date_time_value() function to work.
As in

```
get_date_time_value(Key, Value) :-
 get_time(Stamp),
 stamp_date_time(Stamp, DateTime, local),
 date_time_value(Key, DateTime, Value).
```

However I am at a loss as to how do I call this function from my rule which is defined as

```
rules([[time,0],[
    [1,[_],0,
            [please,do,not,get_date_time_value(time,x),.],
            ['I',dont,know,the,time,.]]]]).
```

Yes this is a homework assignment and this might sound silly to experts ,but I am really new to Prolog programming even though I have quite some experience in object oriented and functional programming.
No matter what parameters I pass to the get_date_time_value(time,X) function I am always getting an error.
I spent all night on a hit an trial approach ,but nothing I do works.
Any pointers will be great!!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the structure I guess it should look something like this:

```
rules([[time,0],[
    [1,[_],0,
            [it,is,HourLiteral,oclock,.],
            ['I',dont,know,the,time,.]]]]) :- get_date_time_value(hour, HourNumber), number_codes(HourNumber, HourString), atom_string(HourLiteral, HourString) .
```

I do not know if it works. I did not test it.

Comment: The PO explicitly stated this is homework: he is being honest and is not asking for the final solution to be given.

Comment: @User I just tested it and it works fine , thanks :)
Should be a nice starting point for my more complicated predicate logic and knowledge base 
eg. 11:59 PM should answer it is almost midnight you should go to sleep now .

Answer (score 1):

You do not give any idea of what you mean by your *rule*. Maybe you are trying to have the current time in the list where the term `get_date_time_value(time,x)` appears: but, is that term a call to a function? Prolog does not support that: just look at the clause you give for the `get_date_time_value/2` **predicate** (not *function*) and what you see there is a sequence of calls to predicates. So your rule probably must given in a clause that holds only if the call to your `get_date_time_value/2` predicate also holds, and the clause head and the call share variable(s) to pass information between them.

Comment: Yes,
I still wrapping my head around the notion of Predicates.
Note to self - I should have paid more attention in my Discrete Math Class :)

Comment: At first using relations (the notion behind predicates) may seem a bit difficult, but learning to use them in programming pays off for some kinds of applications, in particular in AI.